# Ruby on Rails - Missing template error when I am pretty sure I have the template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have this route:

```
scope :module => :mobile, :as => :mobile do
    constraints(:subdomain => /m/) do
      devise_for :users, :path => "", :path_names =>
               { :sign_in => "login", :sign_out => "logout",
                 :sign_up => "signup" },
                 :controllers => {:sessions => "mobile/sessions"}

      resources :home

      resources :disclosures # Will have new, get, look up a disclosure
    end
  end
```

and this controller:

```
class Mobile::SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
  end
end
```

and under this directory: `/app/views/mobile/sessions/new.html.haml`

and this is the code inside the new.html.haml file:

```
= content_for :page_title do
  = t :page_title_login
= content_for :primary_content do
  #login_box
    .span6
      #traditional-login
    .span4
= content_for :before_closing_body_tag do
  configure_login_form(#{request.xhr?.to_s.downcase});
```

But after I log in, I get this error in the browser:

```
Missing template mobile/sessions/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en, :en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:haml, :erb, :builder]}. Searched in: * "/Users/alexgenadinik/projects/cmply/cmply-app/app/views" * "/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/ckeditor-3.6.3/app/views" * "/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/kaminari-0.13.0/app/views" * "/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/devise-2.0.4/app/views"
```

Which suggests to me that the system think that I don't have the new.html.haml file.  But I obviously have that file.  So I am not sure what is the problem.  And idea what I did incorrectly?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error here isn't that you're missing the new.html.haml file; you're missing a create.html.haml or a redirect away from the create action. Usually you redirect after a login, so try changing your controller action to something like this:

```
class Mobile::SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

Or wherever you want the visitor to wind up.

Comment: actually I got an error after doing that.  Maybe in my case I wasn't supposed to redirect to root_url. Where is root_url defined? I am going to need to redirect to user_home or something like that. I ran rake but none of the paths there looked like root_url

Comment: I would need to go to something like the mobile_home path that is in my rake routes, but when I do that, I get an error like: undefined local variable or method `mobile_home' for #<Mobile::SessionsController:0x148d837d8>

Comment: root_url is usually the root of your application. If it isn't defined just select any other route you have defined in your routes.rb to redirect the user to.

Comment: by the way since the controller does a redirect, should there not be a new.html.haml file for the sessions?